# Why does Google Dev Tools not show HTML compression?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, http-compression

I've turned on "Large request rows" so I can see network (compressed) vs. content (uncompressed) sizes.

[image: Google dev tools "Use large request rows"]

There's no way Amazon isn't compressing its HTML. And you can see they're compressing they're stylesheets. So why am I not seeing the compressed size for the homepage's HTML?

[image: Amazon content sizes]

Just for good measure, I've checked the headers. They say the content is gzipped.

[image: The headers say it's compressed]

So am I reading Dev Tools wrong? Is it a bug? I'm very confused.

Comment: See https://crbug.com/763700 - broken in Chrome 63, you can "fix" it by disabling `chrome://flags/#browser-side-navigation`

Comment: Yep, that's the bug, and the fix did work. Want to create an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: IDK. They should fix it soon, supposedly, before 63 is released in the stable channel.

Comment: Fair point... I'll let the question live for a while and kill it off if the fix comes soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wOxxOm pointed out, this is a [bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=763700).